# How to get state to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a catalogue type program for a school project - it pulls in a few arrays and concatenates the arrays with arrays created from user input. The only issue is that they state is always one behind so if you increase the counter to 5 and submit it will return 4 instead. Any ideas?

```
const Booking = ({currentId}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
    const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);
    const filteredRentals = users.filter((users)=> users._id === user?.result?._id);

    const rentedArr = filteredRentals[0].rentedProducts;
    const numbArr = filteredRentals[0].numberOfProducts;

    const [userRental, setUserRental] = useState({rentedProducts:'', numberOfProducts:0});
    const [newRental, setNewRental] = useState({rentedProducts:rentedArr, numberOfProducts:numbArr});

    const userID = user?.result?._id;
    const newRented = rentedArr.concat(userRental.rentedProducts);
    const newNumb = numbArr.concat(userRental.numberOfProducts);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(currentId){
            dispatch(updateRentals(userID, newRental));
        } else {
            console.log('No product found');
        } clear();
    }

    const clear = () =>{
        setUserRental({rentedProducts:'', numberOfProducts:0})
    }

    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        setUserRental({...userRental, numberOfProducts: e.target.value, rentedProducts: product.title});
        setNewRental({...newRental, numberOfProducts: newNumb, rentedProducts: newRented});
    }
    return(
        <div className='booking-panel-wrap'>
            <h3>Book an Item</h3>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="inStock">Units Required:
                    <input type="number" required min="0" name="inStock" onChange={(e) => changeHandler(e)}/>
                </label>
                <button type="submit" className='btn-white'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
    
}

export default Booking;
```

Comment: @3limin4t0r how do you recommend I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`newNumb` and `newRented` within your `changeHandler` are both dependent on `userRental`. `setUserRental` updates `userRental` on the next render, the current `userRental` does not change after calling `setUserRental`. Therefore the values of `newNumb` and `newRented` are incorrect (stale) and should be re-evaluated within the `changeHandler`.

```
const changeHandler = (e) => {
  // store the new `userRental` in a variable, before passing it to `setUserRental()`
  const newUserRental = {...userRental, numberOfProducts: e.target.value, rentedProducts: product.title};
  setUserRental(newUserRental);

  // build `newRental` based on the new value of `userRental` (stored in the `newUserRental` variable)
  const newNumb = numbArr.concat(newUserRental.numberOfProducts);
  const newRented = rentedArr.concat(newUserRental.rentedProducts);
  setNewRental({...newRental, numberOfProducts: newNumb, rentedProducts: newRented});
};
```

The above is probably more complicated than it needs to be. The state `newRental` can probably be removed (or changed into a `useMemo`), which simplifies things quite a lot.

In the example below I removed the `newRental` state completely and build the object as part of the submit action.

```
const Booking = ({currentId}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
    const userID = user?.result?._id;
    const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);
    // If you only need the first match of a `filter()` result, use `find()` instead.
    // `filteredRental` is only used inside `handleSubmit()` so should probably be moved there.
    const filteredRental = users.find((user) => user._id === userID);

    const [userRental, setUserRental] = useState({ rentedProducts: '', numberOfProducts: 0 });

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (currentId) {
            // don't store the newRental in a state, but build it during submit
            const newRental = {
                rentedProducts: filteredRental.rentedProducts.concat(userRental.rentedProducts),
                numberOfProducts: filteredRental.numberOfProducts.concat(userRental.numberOfProducts);
            };
            dispatch(updateRentals(userID, newRental));
        } else {
            console.log('No product found');
        } clear();
    }

    const clear = () =>{
        setUserRental({rentedProducts:'', numberOfProducts:0})
    }

    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        setUserRental({...userRental, numberOfProducts: e.target.value, rentedProducts: product.title});
    }
    
    // ...
}

export default Booking;
```